# how do you print from stackoverflow?

Tags: support, information-display, accessibility

Codeblocks have horizontal scrolling.  So, how can I print from StackOverflow to show all code?  Is there a way to turn horizontal scrolling off?  It's no good for mobility impaired users, anyway, so I'd prefer not to have it on my system.

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com

Comment: @bart ah hahaha.

Comment: Use chrome/chromium File > Print > More settings > Selection only : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291352/217837